# Too many OPTIONS requests

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, axios, preflight

In my application, the front end (ReactJS using axios, if that matters) makes some API calls to the backend (Node/Express, again if that matters). In all of the responses, server does responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` (This is a test environment, appropriate changes will be made to allow specific origins in production).

In the Chrome Developer Tools Network tab, I observe that for every request say `POST /assets` , `POST /filters`, `PUT /media` etc., a preflighted OPTIONS request is sent. Now I do understand [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request), the reason for those and that's fine.

**OPTIONS Request Headers**

```
OPTIONS /api/v1/content/bb54fbf52909f78e015f/f91659797e93cba7ae9b/asset/all 
HTTP/1.1
Host: XX.X.XX.XXX:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36    
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/main/93f1ced0f15f35024402/assets
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.8,mr;q=0.6
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type
Date: Sat, 05 Aug 2017 10:09:16 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

My observation is that this is sent for literally every requests, and repetitively i.e. even if the same request is being made again (immediately or otherwise).

My questions are

1. Is this necessarily a bad thing (i.e. would it cause any performance issues, even minor)?
2. Why doesn't browser remember the header responses for the same server, same request?
3. Is there anything I am missing to configure on the front end or backend for making this sticky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the [`Access-Control-Max-Age`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age) header to tell the browser that it’s OK to cache your other `Access-Control-*` headers for that many seconds:

```
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I do have a follow up question though. As stated in the documentation you linked, there is a timeout on this setting which differs by browsers i.e. 24 hours for FF & 10 minutes for Chrome. Any reasoning for this? I understand we don't want to have the settings cached for indefinite period, but what is a risk of having this open for say 2 hours or 4 hours etc. Also one more question, as it's not clear in the docs, does this cache work out per unique request or is it generic. I mean if server sends header for say /media resource, would it be considered for /user?

Comment: @SubhashDike Re. timeout: given that they are so very different between Fx and Chrome, I guess this is just an arbitrary cutoff that the vendors thought to be a good tradeoff between caution and performance. The [W3C CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) just says “items cannot stay [...] for unreasonable amounts of time”.

Comment: @SubhashDike Re. granularity: according to the [W3C CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), it’s per-URL. But I’m not sure browsers actually follow that spec, as they generally have a lukewarm relationship with W3C.